# replicate section of html dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ember.js

I have a section(`div`) in front end(`html`) that is getting loaded dynamically based upon no of entities in back end. So if there are 5 entities in backend, `div` will be repeated 5 times. But all this happening from javascript which does the repeation. So the current code look like:

```
var template = '<div>';
template += '<div class="row">';
template += '<div class="col-md-3">';
template += '<div class="col-md-3"></div>';
```

and so on. So we are repeating this template variable based upon no of entities in the backend. I know that this is a bad approach. `template` that we are trying to render from javascript has become extremly large and unreadable. its hard to make any changes and I am trying to make it mobile/table responsive and it is giving me nightmares.

I have just started with front end development and don't know much about the approaches I can take here. I know for certain that these kind of things can easily be solved using frontend frameworks like angularjs or emberjs but I am running short on time to learn these frameworks.

What can be the best approach using html/css/js/jquery/ajax that I can go for?

Edit 1: backend here is Python/Django/Django-Rest

Comment: If you want something lighter weight than a full html component library like react or angular or something, you could use a lighter template library like mustache or handlebars.  You can put your template markup in a `<template>` even to keep your markup out of your code.

Comment: do mention the reason for downvote, Note: I have mentioned that I have just started learning front end.

Comment: @recursive updated backend details, not sure how mustache(had a look at pystache) fits in.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ES6 (no other dependencies), **Template literals** is your quick and dirty option.

```
function html(literalSections, ...substs) {
    // Use raw literal sections: we don’t want
    // backslashes (\n etc.) to be interpreted
    let raw = literalSections.raw;

    let result = '';

    substs.forEach((subst, i) => {
        // Retrieve the literal section preceding
        // the current substitution
        let lit = raw[i];

        // In the example, map() returns an array:
        // If substitution is an array (and not a string),
        // we turn it into a string
        if (Array.isArray(subst)) {
            subst = subst.join('');
        }

        // If the substitution is preceded by a dollar sign,
        // we escape special characters in it
        if (lit.endsWith('$')) {
            subst = htmlEscape(subst);
            lit = lit.slice(0, -1);
        }
        result += lit;
        result += subst;
    });
    // Take care of last literal section
    // (Never fails, because an empty template string
    // produces one literal section, an empty string)
    result += raw[raw.length-1]; // (A)

    return result;
}
```

To create a template,

```
  const tmpl = addrs => html`
    <table>
    ${addrs.map(addr => html`
        <tr>$${addr.first}</tr>
        <tr>$${addr.last}</tr>
    `)}
    </table>
  `;
```

You can read more about the process behind this at,

http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/template-strings-html.html